Spin-1 Ising model
We know that for spin-1 ising model i=0,+1,-1. Using mean field theory, I got magnetisation as
$m=\frac{2e^{\beta D}sinh[\beta(zJm+h)]}{1+2e^{\beta D}cosh[\beta(zJm+h)]}$. Taking $D=0$, and expanding around $T_c$ I am getting $$m=\frac{T}{T_c}\sqrt{\frac{T_c}{T}-1}$$. According to universility theorem, the critical exponent has to be $1/2$. But here it is not. What is wrong? Even when I calculate the other exponents, I am not getting the correct answer.

Your formula for the magnetization can be put under the form
$$m={\sqrt T\over Tc}\sqrt{T_c-T}$$
In the neighborhood of the critical temperature, you can approximate the prefactor $\sqrt T$ by $\sqrt{T_c}$, leading to
$$m=\sqrt{T_c-T\over T_c}=\bigg({T_c-T\over T_c}\bigg)^{1/2}$$
which is precisely what you expect for a critical exponent $\beta=1/2$.

More carefully, a Taylor series in $T$ about $T_c$ yields this expression to first non-zero order.
